# SQL помощник с поиском связей между таблицами

Tags: sql

Кому-то уже добрый вечер. Назрел вопрос в том что, а есть ли для СУБД типа mysql, postgreSQL, помощник, который просматривает связи в таблицах и подсказывает. Например у меня есть  запрос:

```
select
    case
        when count(*) = 0 then '-'
        when count(*) >= 2 then 'Ошибка'
        else string_agg(res.name, '')
    end as cascads
from (
select c.name
from cascads c
    inner join branchdevices b on c.id = b.cascade
    inner join connectors c2 on b.id = c2.branchdevice
    inner join line l on c2.line = l.id
    inner join substation s on l.destination = s.id
where
c.id = ?1
group by c.id
) as res
```

Что бы я например вбил

```
from cascads c
inner join substation s on
```

А после он мне предложил бы варианты. Типа такого:

```
from cascads c
    inner join branchdevices b on c.id = b.cascade
    inner join connectors c2 on b.id = c2.branchdevice
    inner join line l on c2.line = l.id
    inner join substation s on l.destination = s.id
```

Или я слишком губу раскатал.))

Comment: Да кому оно надо... всё равно будет ошибаться через раз. Уж лучше создать себе нормальную конвенцию имён и использовать NATURAL JOIN.

Comment: @Akina, дело в том, что БД спроектирована через пень колоду. Это если без мата. И чтобы найти что-то, уходит много времени. Ищу через ERD связи и смотрю где и как добраться. Долго, хотелось бы побыстрее как-то, мозги себе не выносить

Comment: @Akina в целом то можно, используя информацию о внешних ключах, подсказывать какие таблицы джойнить.

Comment: @teran В теории мне тоже показалось что возможно. Есть ли реализованные механизмы где нибудь?

Comment: @teran Можно. Правда, есть как минимум два "но". Во-первых, не всегда таблицы вяжутся по внешним ключам (особенно если в запросе используется несколько копий таблицы - ну тут вообще беда,- или там селф-джойн), во-вторых, зачастую к OUTER связыванию по внешнему ключу добавляются доп. условия. Не, мож, кто и постарался - но меня что-то сомневает. Я уж не говорю о том, что достаточно по схеме один раз создать набор связывающих условий - и можно его тупо копипастить...